# Unable to change max_input_time in php.ini

Tags: php, ubuntu

In Ubuntu I'm trying to change the max_input_time to -1

In php.ini I see the following section:

```
; max_input_time
;   Default Value: -1 (Unlimited)
;   Development Value: 60 (60 seconds)
;   Production Value: 60 (60 seconds)
```

Currently I'm seeing the value as being 60. When I inserted the following command:

```
max_input_time = -1
```

And restart Apache, I see the value has remained the same. My question is, how do I change max_input_time to -1 in php.ini?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just comment the line

```
;max_input_time = 60
```

and it will return to its default value

Comment: Thank you! Perfect answer! I'll be able to accept this answer in about 7 min  :)

Comment: @user2028856 - I've just tested: your `max_input_time = -1` should work fine. There must be something you haven't told us.